# How to Create a HTML API post form that requires a session token?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, api, post

I would like to create a form on my website which will allow users to create a support ticket. This form has to POST to an API which is fine but it has one parameter that I am struggling with. It requires a new token every time the form is submitted.

I am able to generate a new token but I am not sure how to add it to the form as a hidden field. I hope the code below helps you to understand and help me. Thank you for your time and effort.

I have tried searching everywhere but either I don't understand or come up empty. So I am able to create a form that generates the token, and a separate form to create a new support ticket but I can't expect the user to copy the token and add it to the support ticket creation form.

This Form Generates a new Token

```
<form action="api/v1/helpdesk/authenticate" method="post">>
        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="demo"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="password" value="demo"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is the output of the form/post request that generates the token, we only require the token

```
{
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvY29tbXVuaWNhdGlvbi50ZWxzZW5zZS5uZXQuemFcL2VtYWlsXC9wdWJsaWNcL2FwaVwvdjFcL2F1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZSIsImlhdCI6MTU1NjMwNTc2OCwiZXhwIjoxNTU2MzA2MDA4LCJuYmYiOjE1NTYzMDU3NjgsImp0aSI6IkNkZGF1QnF2bG1IZjRMdGIiLCJzdWIiOjIsInBydiI6Ijg3ZTBhZjFlZjlmZDE1ODEyZmRlYzk3MTUzYTE0ZTBiMDQ3NTQ2YWEifQ.iolZNRZWdm3ngMF84XXHd0wRSeqyUze8jnIWZis0v3s",
    "user_id": {
        "id": 2,
        "user_name": "admin",
        "first_name": "System",
        "last_name": "Administrator",
        "gender": 0,
        "email": "admin@telsense.co.za",
        "ban": 0,
        "active": 1,
        "is_delete": 0,
        "ext": "",
        "country_code": 0,
        "phone_number": "",
        "mobile": null,
        "agent_sign": "",
        "account_type": "",
        "account_status": "",
        "assign_group": 1,
        "primary_dpt": 1,
        "agent_tzone": "16",
        "daylight_save": "",
        "limit_access": "",
        "directory_listing": "",
        "vacation_mode": "",
        "company": "",
        "role": "admin",
        "internal_note": "",
        "profile_pic": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/76cea1d3133cd2141b3d9efcfa1be0b8?s=80&r=g&d=identicon",
        "created_at": "2019-04-19 13:00:46",
        "updated_at": "2019-04-23 20:46:13",
        "user_language": null
    }
}
```

This is the form to create a new ticket

```
<form action="api/v1/helpdesk/create" method="post">>
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="dynamically created above"/>
        <input type="email" name="Email Address"/>
        <input type="text" name="Subject"/>
        <input type="text" name="Message"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I would like to be able to only use the form above to create a ticket which will automatically generate a token and then submit. I hope everything was explained well and easy to understand my goals. Thanks again.

Comment: Why do you need this? Can't you just set a session variable when the user logs in?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. This will be on a public page (anyone with link can access) so the user will not need to login. I want to make it as simple and as fast as possible for a user to report an issue.

All I need is for user to go to the page in their browser and complete the form which will then create a ticket in the Helpdesk software(for tracking purposes).

Comment: What language are you creating the form in when you create the token? If it's PHP, you do `<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>"/>`